# Same Sequence of Numpy Functions on Multiple 1D Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

How can I perform the same sequence of Numpy functions on multiple 1D arrays of the same length in Python?

For example:

```
import numpy as np
subtotal1 = np.array([4, 7, 1, 3, 9])
subtotal2 = np.array([5, 3, 6, 5, 2])
...etc.
total = np.array([9, 10, 7, 8, 11])

subtotal1 = np.divide(subtotal1, total)
subtotal1 = np.round(subtotal1 * 100, 1)
subtotal2 = np.divide(subtotal2, total)
subtotal2 = np.round(subtotal2 * 100, 1)
...etc.
```

I am a new Python programmer, and I'm learning Numpy to analyze data and create visualizations. I've searched StackOverflow and the Numpy documentation for days with no luck.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Define a function with those operations (ops) and then use `np.apply_along_axis` on a stacked 2D array? Searching for use cases for that method might help out. Depending on the ops, you might be able to even vectorize those along that axis because `np.apply_along_axis` isn't really a vectorized implementation if you care about performance.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you meant:

```
import numpy as np
subtotal1 = np.array([4, 7, 1, 3, 9],float)
subtotal2 = np.array([5, 3, 6, 5, 2],float)
total = subtotal1+subtotal2

for subtotal in (subtotal1, subtotal2):
    subtotal = np.divide(subtotal, total)
    subtotal = np.round(subtotal * 100, 1)
    print subtotal
```

**Important** if you do not set subtotal1 and 2 as floats, the division is going to give you zeroes (integer division), and that's not what you want.

Since you do not state how you create these subtotals, assuming you can append them to a list as you go, the code is easily generalized:

```
//Create subtotals before
total = sum(subtotals)
for subtotal in subtotals
    subtotal = np.divide(subtotal, total)
    subtotal = np.round(subtotal * 100, 1)
    print subtotal
```

Note your question is not really about `numpy` or `arrays`. Also note the `sum` is not a `numpy` sum - that's different. Read some normal Python tutorials before jumping ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can join all `subtotal` arrays in a 2D array and make the two operations on the whole array. This will result in a line-by-line operations between the two arrays. For that to happen it is necessary that the shape of the two arrays is equal along the second (the column) axis.

```
import numpy as np

subtotal = np.arange(20,dtype=float).reshape((5,4))
total = np.array([8.2,3.4,6.0,1.3])
print subtotal

[[  0.   1.   2.   3.]
 [  4.   5.   6.   7.]
 [  8.   9.  10.  11.]
 [ 12.  13.  14.  15.]
 [ 16.  17.  18.  19.]]

np.round(subtotal/total*100,1)

array([[    0. ,    29.4,    33.3,   230.8],
       [   48.8,   147.1,   100. ,   538.5],
       [   97.6,   264.7,   166.7,   846.2],
       [  146.3,   382.4,   233.3,  1153.8],
       [  195.1,   500. ,   300. ,  1461.5]])
```